# YouTube ActionScript 2.0 Player API not working

Tags: flash, api, youtube

I am a multimedia content developer.

I used "YouTube ActionScript 2.0 Player API Reference" to link movie to my swf stage.

[https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference_as2?hl=zh-TW]

It's work OK one(or two) month ago.

But now, can't link any movie.

This is a big problem with me and our customer.

I think this mistake from FlashPlayer.

Could you please contect your developer to test this part, and response to me.

Thank's a lot.

Best

Jack Chang

Answer (score 0):

They've stopped the AS2 support for this on 2012. I'd suggest you'll start learning AS3, a newer, OOP language. [This is the new, AS3 version.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference?hl=zh-TW)

Comment: I know that maybe to use AS3.0 can solve this problem, but now impossible to re-develop the entire project with AS3.0.

Answer (score 0):

The API still works, it just forces now https connections. If you want further use the Youtube API your SWF files must be located also on a https resource.

The API is still working fine.

Comment: Now i got a more big problem,cuz i can't request all of my customer to used "HTTPS".
Thank's for answer me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to request your customers to use https. You can manage that easily to swap your server side on https with a valid certificate and just change the yt video links, i assume they are stored in a database, from http to https. That's it. Your customers will not be even aware that they were swapped over to https. As far as I have seen, https seems to be mandatory now for using the Youtube API, no matter if you use the AS2 or AS3 API.

And because so many still use older systems, the AS2 API will probably stay available for a few more years but to have at least some security behavior in and around it, I am sure they did the move to force https connections now.

The change took us 30 minutes ;)